# How to prove the independence of the functions of two random variables distributed with multivariate normal.

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

I have to prove this statement on one of my problem sets:

If X1 and X2 are independent random variables, both distributed as N (0,1), then X1+X2 and X1−X2 are independent random variables.

I know that I have to use the properties of the multivariate normal distribution, but I don't know how to.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using the definition?

Comment: Duplicate of this [more general question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1091111/15941) of which the present question is the special case $n=1$.

Comment: I will check your answer!! Thank you !!!